# Listing + pgination using RXJS Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I just started a small angular project, where I have an Article component to list articles with pagination system.
The default page[image]

The main objectives are:

- Display the articles after consuming a GET API ressource.
- Paginating the articles with [ngb-pagination](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/pagination/examples).

My code works perfectly, except that I notice a little refresh of the page each time I paginate to another page. It seems a bad thing for the user experience. I'm sure that my code need a lot of improvements because I'm new with RXJS and Observables manipulation.

This is my `article.component.ts`

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';
import {map} from 'rxjs/internal/operators';
import {Article} from './article.model';
import {ItemResponse} from './item-response.model';
import {ArticleService} from './article.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-article',
  templateUrl: './article.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./article.component.css']
})
export class ArticleComponent implements OnInit {
  public limit = 5;
  public page = 1;
  public total: number;
  public previousPage: number;
  readonly imagePath = `${environment.apiUrl}` + '/..';

  public observable$: Observable<Article[]>;
  public articles: Article[];

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private articleService: ArticleService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadData();
  }

  loadPage(page: number) {
    if (page !== this.previousPage) {
      this.previousPage = page;
      this.loadData();
    }
  }

  loadData() {
    this.observable$ = this.articleService.getArticles(
      new HttpParams()
        .set('page', this.page.toString())
        .set('per_page', this.limit.toString())
    ).pipe(map((res: ItemResponse) => {
      this.page = res.page;
      this.total = res.total;
      this.limit = res.limit;
      return res._embedded.items;
    }));
    this.observable$.subscribe((res: Article[]) => this.articles = res);
  }

  trackElement(index: number, element: any) {
    return element ? element.id : null;
  }

  createRange(len = 6) {
    const arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      arr.push(i);
    }
    return arr;
  }
```

This is my `article.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http';
import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ArticleService {
  private _articlesUrl = `${environment.apiUrl}` + '/articles';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getArticles(params?: HttpParams) {
    return this.http.get(this._articlesUrl, {
      params: params
    });
  }
}
```

this is my `article.component.html`

```
<div class="grid" *ngFor="let article of (articles); trackBy: trackElement">
      <div class="entry-media">
        <img appFadeInAnimation class="animated-background"  [src]="imagePath + article.image">
      </div>
     ...
</div>
```

**The question is:** How to fix the page refresh, to optimize the data loading ? Do i need to to destroy the subscription?

Any help, recommendation, good practices would be appreciated and voted.

Comment: So... What's the question? If this is about code review etc as you mention on the bottom, wrong place to ask.

Comment: Hey, @penleychan I cant have a code review here ? The question is how I can fix that page refresh ?

Comment: If by page refresh I assume you mean the html section of `<div class="grid"...>` being refreshed?

Comment: @penleychan Thank for your time. Yes in fact that div is refreshed.  Do i need to to destroy the subscription?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing how it works, I assume it's because `articles` is not ready yet when you click next page, so it renders empty. Could you do `console.log()` to inspect what's going on inside the subscription?

Comment: It return the data. yes that's it, and normally we should in some way fix the `loadData()` maybe or use kinf of synchronous rxjs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185168/discussion-between-ahmed-bhs-and-penleychan).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in several different ways.
the way I usually handle this kind of situations, is to separate into smart component and dumb components. 
this is a great article about this ([Presentational and Container Components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0).

the way it works is to pass `Observable<Article[]>` to dumb component which only has one job only ( represent data ).

```
<article-items [articles]="articles$ | async"(selectedArticle)="selectedArticle($event)"> </article-items>
```

where

```
this.articles$ = this.articleService.getArticles(
  new HttpParams()
    .set('page', this.page.toString())
    .set('per_page', this.limit.toString())
).pipe(map((res: ItemResponse) => {
  this.page = res.page;
  this.total = res.total;
  this.limit = res.limit;
  return res._embedded.items;
}));
```

in this way, you do not need to subscribe to the data, (async pipe will do it automatically) and do not worry about the unsubscribe.

Comment: thank for your answer, could you please clarify the `article-items.compononent` ? what is it contained ? could you provide me a code example.
And how i gonna recover the `articles$` inside that componenet.

Comment: You can create new component, like any other components, put the tag inside the article.component.html, and in new created component, with @Input() articles: Article[]; you can get all the articles;

Comment: Or you can do this in your current code, without creating new component like: 
<div class="grid" *ngFor="let article of articles$ | async; trackBy: trackElement">
      <div class="entry-media">
        <img appFadeInAnimation class="animated-background"  [src]="imagePath + article.image">
      </div>
     ...
</div>


Here, articles$ is just observable of the return of your service (this.articleService.getArticles); (instead of this.observable$ I just called it articles$, because this way you can have more clear code but it is jus preference )

Comment: Also this is great blog post about async pipe: https://alligator.io/angular/async-pipe/